# Intersection between the sums of the first positive integers, primes and non primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Conjecture : 
$$\left\{\sum\limits_{\begin{array}{c}k=1\\k\in\mathbb{Z}\end{array}}^nk \ |\  n\in\Bbb Z\right\}  \cap
\left\lbrace \sum\limits_{\begin{array}{c}k=1\\k\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\mathbb{P}\end{array}}^nk \ |\  n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\mathbb{P}\right\rbrace \cap
\left\{\sum\limits_{\begin{array}{c}k=2\\k\in\Bbb P\end{array}}^nk\ |\ n\in\Bbb P\right\}= \{ 28 \}$$

(that is : [A000217](http://oeis.org/A000217) $\cap$ [A051349](http://oeis.org/A051349) $\cap$ [A007504](http://oeis.org/A007504) = { 28 } )

In other words : is **28** the only number that can be written as a sum of the first n positive integers (1+2+3+4+5+6+7), m first non primes (1+4+6+8+9) and p first primes (2+3+5+7+11) ?

I didn't find any other number below $10^{14}$ with this property ([Haskell script here](https://github.com/mmai/conjecture28/blob/master/haskell%2FC28.hs)).

EDIT : I cross-posted the question on https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212985/intersection-between-the-sums-of-the-first-integers-primes-and-non-primes

Comment: Clarification: I think "n" is misued in what you wrote.  the conditions on n, integral/non-prime/prime pertain to k, not n, no?  Also, I don't think you want all three sums to have the same upper limit, do you?

Comment: $k$ is a dummy variable. You don't have to write it after the semicolon. I'd write, for example, the third sum, this way:
$$\left\{\sum\limits_{\begin{array}{c}2\le k\le n\\k\in\Bbb P\end{array}}k:n\in\Bbb P\right\}$$

Comment: @lulu n is the last value of k, it belongs to the same set . Theses are sets definitions were n can have all values of respectively Z, Z\P and P.

Comment: @ajotatxe you're right, thanks

Comment: You switched the primes and the non-primes in the text, and I think you meant $\mathbb Z$ where it says $\mathbb P$ in the first set.

Comment: @joriki Thanks. Fixed

Answer (score 10):

Unless there's a systematic reason for these sequences to coincide or avoid each other (which I doubt), we can estimate the number of triple coincidences of these three sequences by integrating over the product of their densities. The first one has density $1/n$ at $a_n=n(n+1)/2$, so at $x$ it has density $\sim(2x)^{-1/2}$. The others both omit numbers, so at given $x$ their densities are lower than this.

Thus we can get an upper bound for the "probability" of there being such numbers beyond some $x_0$ from this integral:

$$
\int_{x_0}^\infty\left(2x\right)^{-3/2}\mathrm dx=(2x_0)^{-1/2}\;.
$$

As you've searched up to $10^{14}$, the "probability" of finding a triple coincidence beyond that is less that one in ten million. Unless there's a systematic reason...

Comment: Clever. This is indeed a good argument in favor of the conjecture.